# binary to float or double assignment error

Tags: java, variable-assignment, binary-data

why assignment of binary to float or double is causing an error.

> here is my first code which works well-

```
float myFloat1 = 0b111; //prints 7.0
double myDouble1 = 0b111; //prints 7.0
```

> here is the second code

```
float myFloat2 = 0b111f; //compiler complains ';' expected
double myDouble2 = 0b111d; //compiler complains ';' expected
```

In the second code compilers complains that ';' expected, what's going on in second code snippet? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Abimaran Kugathasan: I don't understand how is that octal?

Comment: @Abimaran -> integer literal prefixed with 0 is treated as octal, and '8' and '9' aren't valid octal digits.

Comment: @KaribasappaGC:Yeah that's right. Agree

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan:Well I don't have any integer literal in my code.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey : Yes, If you have a integer literal only you have to append `f` or `d`.

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan:Everything in my code is binary value.

Comment: @Mr.Pandey : Check my updated answer, I wrongly said, it's octal, it's binary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0bxxx` specifies an integer, but this can't be modified with `d` or `f` to convert it to a floating-point value. But you can use a cast:

```
float myFloat2 = (float) 0b111;
double myDouble2 = (double) 0b111;
```

Comment: :How about long type.                                         long myLong1=0b101010101010101010101010101010L;                       long myLong1=0b101010101010101010101010101010;                        print 715827882 in both above lines.

Comment: Then you answered your own questioh

Comment: :No, I mean if long is printing it in both ways then why not float and double?

Comment: Because [that's what the spec says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1). A valid integer literal can have the suffix `l` or `L`. A valid floating-point literal can have the suffix `f`, `d`, `F`, or `D`. `0b111` is an integer literal.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you just use `float x=7;`

then it assumes 7 is integer and trying to assign to float so compile time error comes

so to make it work we have to do

```
float x=7f;
```

but if the number is starting with 0 in java it assumes it as Octal number

and for octal number you should not append anything like f or d.
so `float x=0b111;` is fine instead of `float x =0111f;`

also remember `float x=0181;` is invalid because octal number should have digits only from 0 to 7 and its having one of the digit 8.